# Php Variable Variables

Tags: php, variable-assignment

Ive got some generated arrays, and their variable names stored in another array like the following

```
$array1 = 4x119 array;
$array2 = 4x119 array;
etc ..
$var1= [
"array1",
"array2",
etc...
];
```

and trying to loop though them like this

```
foreach ($var1 as $loopitem){
var_dump($$loopitem[3]);
}
```

How can i make this less ambiguous ?

Currenly im fairly sure its looking for a variable called the contents of `$loopitem[3]` instead of looking at `$arr1[3]` as without the [3] the var dump returns correct

Without the [3]

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(119) { 

rest of output
```

With [3]

```
NULL
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `${$loopitem}[3]` to make it readable and unambiguous. Actually I'd *always* use that syntax for variable variables since `$$foo` is easy to misread as `$foo`.

However, it would be even better not to use them at all and use an array instead!

Comment: Great ! Thats working. I cant accept the answer yet but will when the time limit is up. Thanks !

Comment: The best part of the answer is to AVOID VARIABLE VARIABLES! If you can create a separate array with the names of the arrays, you can also create one big array with the other arrays included. If all else fails, go for `$var1 = ['array1' => $array1, 'array2' => $array2,];`